# Browsersync only reloads on html change

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I am new to using gulp and browsersync. I am attempting to have it so whenever I make a change in any of my files: css, js, or html the live preview will refresh and show me the changes. I have made tasks that all work when they are called but once I run my browserSync it only refreshes on my index.html changes.

```
// Gulp.js configuration
var
  // modules
gulp = require('gulp'),
newer = require('gulp-newer'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
htmlclean = require('gulp-htmlclean'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
assets = require('postcss-assets'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker'),
cssnano = require('cssnano'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),


  // development mode?
  devBuild = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),

  // folders
  folder = {
    src: 'src/',
    dist: 'dist/'
  };

//image processing
gulp.task('images', function(){
    var out = folder.dist + 'images/';
    return gulp.src(folder.src + 'images/**/*')
        .pipe(newer(out))
        .pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 5}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(out));
});

//HTML processing
gulp.task('html', ['images'], function(){
var
    out = folder.dist + 'html/',
    page = gulp.src(folder.src + 'html/**/*')
        .pipe(newer(out));

//minify production code
if(!devBuild){
    page = page.pipe(htmlclean());
}

return page.pipe(gulp.dest(out))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// JS processing

gulp.task('js', function(){
    var out = folder.dist + 'scripts/';
    return gulp.src(folder.src + 'scripts/**/*')
        .pipe(newer(out))
        .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(out))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

//CSS processing
gulp.task('css', ['images'], function(){
    var postCssOpts = [
        assets({ loadPaths: ['images/'] }),
        autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', '>2%'] }),
        mqpacker
        ];

    if(!devBuild) {
        postCssOpts.push(cssnano);
    }

    return gulp.src(folder.src + 'styles/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
          outputStyle: 'nested',
          imagePath: 'images/',
          precision: 3,
          errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(postcss(postCssOpts))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.dist + 'styles/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('run', ['html', 'css', 'js']);

// watch for changes
gulp.task('watch',['browserSync', 'css'], function() {

  // image changes
  gulp.watch(folder.src + 'images/**/*', ['images']);

  // html changes
  gulp.watch(folder.src + 'html/**/*', ['html']);

  // javascript changes
  gulp.watch(folder.src + 'js/**/*', ['js']);

  // css changes
  gulp.watch(folder.src + 'css/scss/**/*', ['css']);

});

gulp.task('default', ['browserSync','run', 'watch'])


gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir:'dist',
            directory: true
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You might try .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true)); instead of the stream() calls at the end of each task.  That sometimes helps.   Also (unrelated) since your 'default' already calls 'browserSync', take browserSync out of your 'watch' task.  And since the 'run' task already calls 'css', take 'css' out of the 'watch' task dependency too.

Comment: @Mark I tried those tips and unfortunately it did not work. The HTML still updates but nothing else.